# Can one show that hypernuclei are always unstable?

Tags: nuclear-physics, hadron-dynamics, exotic-matter

Normal atomic nuclei are composed of protons and neutrons, where the local interactions stabilize the neutrons that are unstable in isolation. [Hypernuclei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypernucleus) have one or more strange hadrons beside the protons and neutrons, such as Helium-5-$\Lambda$. Since strangeness is conserved they are only "stable" until the hadron decays.

However, the local nuclear environment changes the decays. For example, it makes the decays $\Lambda+n\rightarrow n+n +$ 176 MeV and $\Lambda + p \rightarrow n+p+$176 MeV happen instead of the usual $\Lambda\rightarrow p+\pi^-$ and $\Lambda \rightarrow n+\pi^0$ [due to Pauli blocking of the pions](https://www.europhysicsnews.org/articles/epn/pdf/2002/05/epn02501.pdf). There are even [magic hypernuclei](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.04865), at least in theory.

So, is there any way of showing that hypernuclei will always be unstable?